American movie from late 2000, a young girl and and old man go about killing people
There're two main characters:

a young girl who hates people around her because of their careless..or..ignorance. She so much hates this one particular girl from her school who stars in reality show, asks her parents to buy a particular car but they buy something else and she cries about it on TV acting like a brat. 
an old man who has insomnia(probably). His neighbor is so inconsiderate making all kinds of noises in this house and parking his car blocking this old man driveway. 

These two somehow meet each other, then steal this neighbors camero/charger car. They go to the girls school and blow up the car of this brat girl she hates. They also kill some people i guess, i don't remember much of it. 
Can someone please tell me the name of this movie. 
Thanks!

I think its "God Bless America" 




yes thanks. this was the movie.

Can you post a Wikipedia or imdb link so that others might see what movie it is?
